# I am getting error "Cannot populate the required constructor argument: dio."

Tags: json, flutter, serialization, dio

app_api.dart
'''

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'package:mvvm/data/responces/responces.dart';
import 'package:retrofit/http.dart';

import '../../app/constant.dart';

part 'app_api.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
@RestApi(baseUrl: Constant.baseURL)
abstract class AppServiceClient {
  factory AppServiceClient(DioMixin dio, {String baseUrl}) = _AppServiceClient;

  @POST("/customers/login")
  Future<AuthenticationResponce> login();
}
'''
pubspec.yaml file
'''
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.2 <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.5
  retrofit:
  dio:
  analyzer: ^6.0.0

  json_annotation: ^4.8.1
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2



dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^2.1.4
  json_serializable: ^6.7.1
  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

'''

'''

```
I getting error in terminal 
PS F:\AndroidStudio\FlutterProjects\mvvm> dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 261ms
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph completed, took 61ms
[INFO] Checking for updates since last build completed, took 531ms
[SEVERE] json_serializable on lib/data/network/app_api.dart:

Cannot populate the required constructor argument: dio.
package:mvvm/data/network/app_api.dart:14:11
   ╷
14 │ '''  `factory AppServiceClient(DioMixin dio, {String baseUrl}) = _AppServiceClient;`'''
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
[INFO] Running build completed, took 1.9s
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 30ms
[SEVERE] Failed after 1.9s
```

'''
i am getting above error while running build runner its not able populate constructor dio could someone help me
i am getting above error while running build runner its not able populate constructor dio could someone help me
i am getting above error while running build runner its not able populate constructor dio could someone help me